# Mysql left join not returning null values

Tags: mysql

i have a table called users which has users and respective referralIds. Some of the users do not have referralIds and are NULL.

I have a second table called transactions where sum(transactions.amount) will give me the revenue that the customer generated as long as transaction_type = 1

Problem: I am doing a left join that will show me revenue generated per referralId. I want a group by that shows me revenue generated by users that do not have referralIds a well. However, Null referralId is returning NULL revenue as well

```
SELECT
 users.referralId, b.revenue 
 FROM users
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         users.referralId, SUM(transactions.amount) AS revenue
    FROM
        transactions
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = transactions.username
    WHERE
        transaction_type = 1 and date(created_at) between @start_date and @end_date
    GROUP BY users.referralId) b ON users.referralId = b.referralId
group by referralId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case consider doing a `INNER JOIN` instead in your outer query. Moreover, don't see a reason why you need that outer query at all. Your inner subquery should be able to get the required data.

```
SELECT
 users.referralId, b.revenue 
 FROM users
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         users.referralId, SUM(transactions.amount) AS revenue
    FROM
        transactions
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = transactions.username
    WHERE
        transaction_type = 1 and date(created_at) between @start_date and @end_date
    GROUP BY users.referralId) b ON users.referralId = b.referralId
group by referralId
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT **OUTER** JOIN worked for me. you should give it a try